# How do I perform addition of 2 fractions in Java?

Tags: java

I have 2 classes, 'FractionCalculator' class and 'Fraction' class. I have written the code but I have no idea how to I execute the addition process in the 'FractionCalculator' class. I know how to access other methods like getters, setters, and toString but I have no idea how to execute the 'addition' code. Please help.

---

```
public class FractionCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fraction f = new Fraction(9, 6);
        ;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Fraction {
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    Fraction(int num, int den) {
        numerator = num;
        denominator = den;

        if (den == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not possible to use denominator zero");
        } else if (den<0) {
            numerator = num * -1;
            denominator = den * -1;
        } else {
            this.numerator = num;
            this.denominator = den;
        }
    }

 //Method

    public int getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }

    public int getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return numerator+"/"+denominator;
    }

    public double toDouble() {
        return numerator/denominator;
    }

    public Fraction add(Fraction other) {
        Fraction addFraction = new Fraction(((numerator*other.denominator)+(other.numerator*denominator)),(denominator*other.denominator));
        return addFraction;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, how would you do it by hand? Do you actually understand the steps that need to be taken in order to add two fractions? If not, then you have a math question, not a programming question. If you do understand, then I don't know why you have a question - just follow through the steps.

Comment: Wait, hold on. Are you saying that you want to *use* the `add` method that already exists, and don't know how? I think you are lying to yourself - you call methods the same way no matter what their purpose is. You already know how to call methods (like you said, you can call getters and setters and `toString`).

Comment: Yeah I'm not lying ! Is it by using this code in the 'FractionCalculator' class, System.out.println(f.add(3,5));  ? I tried this but it seems like it doesnt work. Please help Im not joking

Comment: Okay. See where it says `public Fraction add(Fraction other) {`? What do you think the `Fraction other` part means? Also, please read [ask]. If you tried an approach to the problem and you got an error message, then your question **is not** "how do I do this?"; your question is "why do I get this error message when I try the following code?". And if the problem is with calling an existing method, then the question is about calling that method, not about solving the problem for which the method was written.

Comment: That's the other fraction. I really have no idea. You mean I should use 'f.add(Fraction x,y)' ?

Comment: It says that you can only `.add` another `Fraction`. So you have to create that one first, yes.

Comment: I figure it ! 
Fraction f = new Fraction(1, 1);
Fraction addFraction = new Fraction(1,1);
System.out.println(f.add(addFraction));

Thanks !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.